# Why is my catch block looping forever?

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, try-catch

I am doing a program that calculates factorials, and I wrote a loop that catches NumberFormatException and InputMismatchException. The NumberFormatException runs fine and loops back to the try block, but the InputMismatchException displays its message over and over again without looping back to the try block. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Factorial 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Factorial Test Program\n");

    boolean success = false;

    while (!success)
    {   
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
            int number = s.nextInt();

            if (number < 0) throw new NumberFormatException();

            long f = number;

            for (int i = number-1; i>0; i--)
                f *= i;

            if (number==0) f=1;

            System.out.printf("The factorial of %s is %s.\n", number, f);
            success=true;

            System.out.println("Done!");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Factorial of this value cannot be represented as an integer");
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("You must enter an integer - please re-enter:");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: not you catch block looping forever but while loop ...

Comment: Because you're never successful.

Comment: No it'snot the entire while block looping, it's just the contents of the InputMismatchException block that loop forever. If it looped back to the beginning of the while loop, it would be fine.

Comment: An exception CANNOT loop. The while loop loops, and it keeps throwing the same exception. This is an important point to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once an invalid integer is entered `s.nextInt()` continously passes the newline character through the `while` loop and the process repeats itself *ad infinitum*. On the other hand, when the `NumberFormatException` occurs, a valid integer has already been read, so there's no newline character being passed through to the `while` loop.

Adding `s.nextLine()` within the `InputMismatchException` exception block will correct this issue.

Comment: Why does one exception work fine while the other loops forever?

Comment: When the `NumberFormatException` occurs you have already successfully read an integer so there's no newline character being passed through to the `while` loop

Comment: Okay, so the s.nextInt() fails on the exception, and as such, the input buffer doesn't change? So it's basically automatically entering the invalid data before I get a chance to type anything? Shouldn't I still be able to see "Enter an integer number: " though? I don't. It's just "You must enter an integer - please re-enter:" over and over again.

Comment: If you look you should see both msgs on the same line i.e. `Enter an integer number: You must enter...`

Comment: AH! That I do. Thanks. Wasn't catching that before.

Answer (score 0):

add `break;` in the catch block.
or make the while loop inside the try block

```
try {

    while() {

    }

} catch () { 

}
```